# Can tags contain the word 'coffee'?

Tags: discussion, tags

This was inspired by a few recent posts. Currently we have a couple of tags: [ground-coffee](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ground-coffee) and [flavored-coffee](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flavored-coffee) that contain the word. While the second could lose it easily enough (maybe [flavorings](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flavorings) would be nicer?), what about the first? [ground](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ground) doesn't feel quite right, but neither does having 'coffee' in the tag.

So this question is two fold:

1. Should the word coffee be removed/banned from all tag names?
2. If so, what do we do with the existing ones that do have it?

Comment: Funny, I had [un-asked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)) this [very same question](http://meta.coffee.stackexchange.com/q/77/262) mere hours before this...

Answer (score 6):

Personally I don't think that coffee should be removed from the tags unless it is very redundant.

For example, the tag  [flavored-coffee](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flavored-coffee) would be much more ambiguous as [flavoring](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flavoring) or [flavor](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flavor). You could then be talking about the flavor of the coffee, or adding flavor shots to a coffee. I think that in certain tags, especially ones like [flavored-coffee](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flavored-coffee), we need to keep the word **coffee**. I feel like [ground-coffee](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ground-coffee) needs to have the word coffee in it too.

In other situations, such as [dark-roast-coffee](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-roast-coffee), I think that it could be removed entirely. That example is just a hypothetical one though to show where it does get redundant.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think "coffee" needs to be banned outright from tags, though if others disagree I won't hold that position at all strongly.

If you *do* want to remove it from tags, I might suggest replacing the existing ones with [grinding](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grinding) and [flavoring](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flavoring). They're a little less odd than just [ground](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ground) and [flavor](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flavor), especially because [flavor](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flavor) is more likely to describe questions about how different types and styles of bean, grind, or preparation can affect flavor--which is a different topic entirely from discussing flavored coffee.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if it would be obvious from the context that a tag refers to coffee (this is a coffee Q&A site, after all), we might as well leave it out. However, I don't see the need for a hard-and-fast rule here (or indeed, in most places on StackExchange sites).

As others have mentioned, other tags may *need* the word coffee in them for clarification (eg. [flavored-coffee](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flavored-coffee), which is not the same thing as [flavor](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flavor), or even [flavoring](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flavoring)).

Answer (score -2):

No, no question should not have that tag.

It is weird having that tag when the ***site*** itself is about coffee. It's not an factor or aspect of coffee, it **is** coffee. Having "coffee" is probably not acceptable. If you can't find the tag you need, get to 125 rep and make a new one.

Like the others, people can *include* coffee in their tags for more detail. I'm perfectly fine with that and so are the mods.